# Getting Facebook posts where my page is tagged using facebook's webhook-subscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

Am using Facebook subscription feature for getting the feeds on my pages. Am successfully getting the posts, comments, likes, edits in posts and comments. But am not getting other user's or other page's post where my page is mentioned. Is there any way to get those posts too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get posts on your Page, but not posts from elsewhere. That´s what the webhooks are for, to get updates on your Page.

Comment: Hey thanks. But I thought subscription will get me posts in which my page is "tagged". So there is no way to get these "posts" using subscription right?

Comment: no, subscriptions will get you stuff that is happening on your page